# How to use own function to replace array element in array returned from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, pdo

I've been looking all afternoon and can't find a solution to my problem.

I query my database using PDO to get a set of rows containing data.  I get the 'title', 'content' and the 'postdate' for many rows in my query.

I query the database like this

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title, content, postdate FROM mytable");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

At the moment I have 6 rows and for each row, I want to trim the amount of words in the 'content' field.  I have a function to trim the amount of words like this

```
function trunc($phrase, $max_words) {

    $phrase_array = explode(' ',$phrase);

    if(count($phrase_array) > $max_words && $max_words > 0)
        $phrase = implode(' ',array_slice($phrase_array, 0, $max_words)).'...';

    return $phrase;
}
```

To use my function I use

```
trunc($string_to_be_truncated, 60);
```

What I am having trouble with is replacing what is in the array return from the database with the cut down words in the 'content' field

Basically, I want to cut the amount of words for each of the 'content' fields in the array.

I have been getting a variety of errors for whatever i try such as illegal offset etc.

I haven't got any examples of what I've tried as I've tried so many things but nothing worked.

Comment: I tested your code its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to iterate through the array like this

```
foreach($result as $key=>$result_row)
{
    $result[$key]['content'] = trunc($result_row['content'], 60);
}
```

That should replace the value in the original array with the shortened value.  You have to access the original array.

Comment: Will that keep the same array?

Comment: Many thanks Thoruko.  I knew it had to be simple but I couldn't rack my brains around it